# String with line breaks

Tags: android, ios, string, text, line-breaks

My app avaliable for iOS and Android.
With EditText helpfull in iOs app you can send String (its plain text) to Parse.com. In Parse i can see this text:

```
texttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttext

texttexttexttexttexttext

texttexttexttexttexttext
```

So this text with line breaks.

But when i download this string to Android i can see this:

```
texttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttext
```

Text without breaks. But on Parse.com there are 3 line breaks in this text. 
**How can i do text on Android with line breaks (like on iOS)?**

P/S/ i **can't** do something like **HTMLformatting**, because user on iOS and Android **mustn't see some code elements**, **only text**.

Comment: How are you displaying it now?  \n characters work as linebreaks in a TextView, so if you're downloading the data with newlines it should work.  If you're using some other weird format, we'd need to know what to even attempt to answer.

Comment: @GabeSechan , no, text doesn't contains \n . Actually, i'm truing to ask how can i convert symbol on Ios (line breaks - new line on keyboard) to this specific \n . Or another variance, that can work on the both types of the phones

Comment: I know mac uses \r as a linebreak, iOS may do the same-  in which case converting \r to \n would be fairly safe.  Not 100% sure that's what iOS uses though.